# Does the Flumefire Rage feat allow you to cast blasting spells while raging?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Flumefire Rage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/flumefire-rage/) is the feat that adds +1 damage for every die you roll when casting a fire damage spell, at the risk of becoming Fatigued.

If you are raging, the risk of getting Fatigued lessens, and the damage bonus increases; on the other hand, usually, you need things like [Furious Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/furious-spell-metamagic/) if you want to cast under such circumstances.

What intrigues me, though, is the following passage in the Flumfire Rage description:

> This feat does not **otherwise** grant you the ability to cast spells while raging.

Emphasis mine. Does the word "otherwise" mean that while this feat doesn't help you cast any non-blasting spells when raging, you don't need Furious Spell when raging and casting a Fireball?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No.

I agree that “otherwise” is an awkward word choice there, but ultimately you can’t read that much into it—if Flumefire Rage is going to give you the ability to cast spells in a rage, it’s going to have to say that it does that. It doesn’t say that. And that line looks very much as though it was specifically *intended* to say that the feat doesn’t do that, that it just improves your spellcasting when you have that ability from elsewhere.

Comment: I would also note that one possible prerequisite is bloodrage, which already allows some spells to be cast while raging and has a feat (Mad Magic) that expands that to all spells.

Comment: This answer is supported by the spell's [developer](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ulwa?Raging-Blood-and-Flumefire-Rage-will-it-blend#4)